# Add multiple artifacts from tasks in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to create multiple jars from a single project that should be published to a maven repo, but I can't seem to get the artifact-details correct.

From examples I've seen handling sources-jar, I tried to create (dynamically) several tasks that should create each jar.

```
def environments = ['local', 'dev', 'test', 'acc', 'prod']

environments.each { e ->
    task "create${e}jar"(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) << {
       def dir = filterPropertiesForEnv(e)

       from (dir)
       classifier = e
    }

    artifacts.add('archives', tasks["create${e}jar"])
}


File filterPropertiesForEnv(envName) {
    println "filter for $envName"
    def destDir = new File(project.buildDir, envName)

    destDir.mkdir()

    // Do filter stuff based on each envName

    destDir
}
```

When I run the "install" task, my dynamically created task "create[name]jar" is run, but it doesn't create any jar-file. If I remove the doLast-"<<", the build produces several jar-file, but the jar file is built before everything else is executed (during the configure-stage) so it does only contain a manifest file.

Is there a better way of creating multiple jars and attaching them as artifacts? I will also need to create several ear-files based on the same pattern, where this jar is included, so it would be nice to find a reusable solution.
I'm fluent in Maven, but Gradle is a new acquaintance and I haven't really got to grips with how to structure these kind of problems!

Comment: So you want to publish a different jar for each environment? And publish those with an uploadArchives task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation in the matter I found that if you add a closure to the from-method, the evaluation will be done at runtime instead of configuration-time.

A working solution would then be:

```
def environments = ['local', 'dev', 'test', 'acc', 'prod']

environments.each { e ->
    task "create${e}jar"(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) << {

       from {
           filterPropertiesForEnv(e)
       }
       classifier = e
    }

    artifacts.add('archives', tasks["create${e}jar"])
}


File filterPropertiesForEnv(envName) {
    println "filter for $envName"
    def destDir = new File(project.buildDir, envName)

    destDir.mkdir()

    // Do filter stuff based on each envName

    destDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to publish a different jar for each environment? And publish those with an uploadArchives task?

The best way to do this would probably be to create a subproject for each environment. That way you can have an upload task for every subproject. From the code you posted, it appears you have the code for the different environment in different directories already.

If you are doing some crazy stuff where you filter different files out of one big code base to try to create a Jar file for different environments, that is probably never going to work.

Comment: I'm trying to replace an Ant build in a legacy system, so I would really like to not move any of the source around.

Comment: The resources are placed in a single directory where all generic files are stored, and the settings used for each environment are stored in subfolders, which during build-time is copied to the parent folder.

This pattern is used in about ten systems, so it would be nice if it could be a reusable solution without having to copy a lot of tasks for each system!

There must be a way to publish jars 'on-the-fly'?